# print only the repeating character if adjacent characters are same

Tags: java

I am new to java programming and my requirement is

INPUT: "aaabaccuuuou"
OUTPUT : "aaaccuuu"

Return only the Repeating character and avoid if the character is not adjacent to the previous character.

i have tried the below code . but it is giving output as "aaaabccuuuuo"

which is not considering the adjacent character.please help me .

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sort {




              public static void main(String[] args) {
                     String str = "aaavvvtccatz";
                     int i =0;
                     String o = "";
                     String lo = "";
                     int count = 0 ;

                     char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
                     Set<Character> charSet = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
                     for (char c : chars) {
                         charSet.add(c);
                     }

                     StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                     for (Character character : charSet) {
                         sb.append(character);
                     }
                     /*System.out.println(sb.toString());*/


                     for(int j =0;j<sb.length();j++)
                     {

                           String a = sb.substring(j,j+1);

                           for(i=0;i<str.length();i++)
                           {

                                  String b = str.substring(i, i+1);
                                  if(b.equals(a) )
                                  {
                                         count = count +1;
                                         lo = lo + a;


                                  }
                                  else
                                  {
                                         count = count;



                                  }


                           }

                           /*System.out.println(a);*/
                           /*System.out.println(count);*/

                           if(count > 1 )
                           {
                                  for(int h =0; h <count ;h++)
                                  {
                                         o = o + a ;
                                  }


                           }


                           count = 0;



                     }
                     System.out.println(o);






              }
}
```

Note: the Code quality and Standard may not be up to pro level.since i am learning basic and pushing my limits . **please don't help me by providing the code,help me by providing the logic to find the output**  .thanks .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Is the question about some `IndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: @RC. am not getting any error as IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: What is your question? Are you facing any exceptions or is the logic not working as expected?

Comment: @Uma Kanth : yes logic is not working as expected . it is not considering the adjacent character for comparing .

Comment: Please note am not facing any exception error .problem is the logic . am not able to deduce a logic to get the required output.please dont help me by providing the code . please teach me how to do fishing dont catch a fish for me .

Comment: Can you please explain the test case?

Answer (score 1):

The General idea behind the code below are:

- It is not relevant to look at `index = 0` since it does not really fit to the criteria of the usecase.
- We use `StringBuilder` so that we can improve the string concatination.
- The reset is intended to flag for the previous letter if it is appended already. Without it, we will see a repeating characters.
- Previous character == `chars[x - 1]` and Current character == `chars[x]`.

You can try this

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "aaabaccuuuouu";
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
        boolean unreset = true;
        for (int x = 1; x < chars.length; x++) {
            if (chars[x - 1] == chars[x]) {
                if (unreset) {
                    builder.append(chars[x - 1]);
                    unreset = false;
                }
                builder.append(chars[x]);
            } else {
                unreset = true;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
 }
```

> Sample Testcase: input : aaabaccuuuouu output :  aaaccuuuuu

Comment: Can you please explain me the test case? I think I didn't get the question correctly.

Comment: This is your first example `"aaabaccuuuou" OUTPUT : "aaaccuuu"` then you commented another example like `aaabaccuuuouu output: aaaccuuuuu` so I am expecting that `aaabuu` would have an output of `aaauu` and **not** **aauu**.

Comment: @SanketMakani the goal is to trim the string with no adjacent letters :)

Comment: Yup, Got it! Thanks. :)

Comment: @Enzokie : yes you are correct and your answer is correct . i didnt use the Boolean logic which you have used .so when ever am appending the character am getting one less . i.e. instead of aaabuu i was getting aau

Comment: @user7334955 :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic I followed when writing the following code can be summarized like this:

- Get the received string in to some format that can be iterated through
- while iterating, compare each character with previous one and add it to output string
- as this will skip the first char of found sequences we have to keep track if we have found a sequence so we can add the additional character. This char represents the skipped char.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[ ] args) {
    System.out.println(getRepeatingChars("aaabaccuuuou"));
}

public static String getRepeatingChars(String testString){
    if(testString == null || testString.equals("") || testString.length() == 1){
        return "";
    }

    String resultString = new String();
    char[] charArray = testString.toCharArray();
    boolean isInSequance = false;

    for(int i = 1; i < charArray.length; i++){  
        if(charArray[i] == charArray[i-1]){
            // current character is same as previous
            resultString += charArray[i];
            // raise flag that we have found a repeating sequence
            isInSequance = true;
        }else if(isInSequance){
            // the current char is not same es previous but we have just left a sequence so add one more char to result string - the last char from last sequence
            resultString += charArray[i-1];
            isInSequance = false;
        }else if(isInSequance && i == charArray.length - 1){
            // add last char in string if it is part of a sequence
            resultString += charArray[i];
        }
    }

    return resultString;
}
```

Comment: if the INPUT is :aaabaccuuuouu then output should be aaaccuuuuu,but is giving aaaccuuuu . last character is getting rejected